# 1204_HWE_EOL and Pentium III

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, hardware-enablement-stack

I have a home server running Ubuntu server 12.04 on a Pentium III 933MHz. It has been working well for quite a while - mainly minidlna, samba, and transmission-bt.

When 14.04 was released I did a clean install, struggled to find minidlna but all was well EXCEPT it would hang often. So I reinstalled 12.04 and all was well.

Now I am getting this 1204 HWE EOL message. So I followed the instructions to install the trusty packages. And - guess what? - it hangs all the time. Have to push the reset button. So I downgraded to 12.04 and again all is well.

Is the 14.04 kernel and HWE not compatible with a Pentium III?

Shall I just ignore these messages and continue with 12.04. The packages are all up to date except for the kernel.